# Compilers that support argument-dependent lookup

Tags: c++, boost, argument-dependent-lookup

In our codebase we use extensively [boost::intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) and after moving some headers around I started to get unexpected compilation errors from clang:

```
In file included from C:/code/Signal.cpp:1:
In file included from C:/code/signal.h:3:
In file included from c:/boost_1_56_0/include/boost/smart_ptr.hpp:26:
In file included from c:/boost_1_56_0/include/boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp:16:
c:/boost_1_56_0/include/boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.hpp:68:34: error: call to function 'intrusive_ptr_add_ref' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
        if( px != 0 && add_ref ) intrusive_ptr_add_ref( px );
```

There are [similar issues reported elsewhere](https://github.com/sercantutar/profiny/issues/1).
Our code that uses [boost::intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) was written a while ago and defines all these freestanding function (like `intrusive_ptr_add_ref`) in `boost` namespace. After checking what was the reason of compilation errors that I started to get, it appears that I should define these functions in my namespace instead. From [description of intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html#Introduction):

> On compilers that support [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup),
>   `intrusive_ptr_add_ref` and `intrusive_ptr_release` should be defined in
>   the namespace that corresponds to their parameter; otherwise, the
>   definitions need to go in namespace boost.

I assume most modern compilers do support [ADL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup), however, I couldn't find definite information on what compilers support and what do not support ADL.

So, here's the question: what are these compilers that do not support ADL. I'm primarily interested in microsoft compilers (VS2012, VS2015), and faily recent versions of gcc and clang.

Comment: All the compilers you mention support ADL.  It's not optional.  A compiler must support ADL or be an awful compiler.

Comment: @DrewDormann I do not know about the others, but at least MS had had bugs in its ADL implementation even in fairly recent versions.

Comment: @hvd anything specific about which version had these issues?

Comment: @Pavel A quick search gives that VS2013 had an issue with ADL. Whether that specific issue is relevant to the question, I do not know.

Comment: You can scour the boost sources for conditional compilation macros that show where workarounds have been put in place. I wager you will find that the workarounds are pretty old, and the compilers that select them even older.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yeh01cw(v=vs.90).aspx), ADL support was added in Visual Studio 2008.

With some difficulty, I was able to build EGCS 1.1, the first GCC version that claimed to support namespaces, released in 1997. I tested it by compiling and running the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
namespace foo {
    class bar {};
    void baz(bar&) {
        puts("foo::baz");
    }
}

void baz(const foo::bar&) {
    puts("::baz");
}

int main() {
    foo::bar bar;
    baz(bar);
}
```

It printed `foo::baz`, which is correct. So basic ADL functionality existed in GCC even back in those days. I doubt you could even build Boost using a compiler that old.

Clang 2.7 also gets it right. Note that LLVM 2.7, released in 2010, was the first version of LLVM to ship with C++ support in Clang enabled by default. There are older versions of the Clang C++ frontend, but I don't think they were widely used, and I am too lazy to try to build them from SVN.